# Is it possible to connect the database created in asp.net core mvc using the EF (Entity Framework) Core to Azure cloud for further integration

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm currently working on an Asp.net Core 2.1 MVC application. I would like to create the database using EF Core ( Entity Framework ). And I want to connect that database to Microsoft Azure cloud. And I heard that it's not possible or not that easy to connect the database, which is created using Entity Framework Core, to Azure cloud. Hence I had to create a JSON file instead. But I want to create a database using EF core and I want to know whether I will be able to connect it to Azure.

Comment: If you mean a Azure Sql database, yes it is absolutely possible and not that hard to connect to an Azure Sql database => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-core

Comment: Where did you hear it was hard to connect? The first thing you should do is try connecting. It's really not that much different to connecting to a normal SQL Server database

Comment: No actually using EF core we are creating a SQL database. There is sql server in it  by default. I want to know whether i'd be able to connect that sql database which i create using the EF core to MS Azure.

Comment: "connect that sql database which i create using the EF core to MS Azure" do you mean you want two seperate databases synchronising information or do you mean that you want your app to connect to SQL Azure instead of the local db you created? Please explain - so far this question makes no sense

Comment: yes i want my app to connect to SQL Azure instead of the local db i created. Btw, sorry if there is any mistake in my question.